# Concat rows based on condition in columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where I would like to concat certain rows based on a condition in another column. The dataframe looks like this:

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aaaa aa | lay | other data | more data |
| bbb bb b | lay | data | more_data |
| make ccccc | lay | other_data | data |
| rake cccc | lay | other_data | data |
| ddd dddd d | may | data more | other data |
| make eeeee | may | more data | data |

In col2, if the values are the same, I would like to concat the row which always starts with make and rake to the rest of the string in col1 without effecting the data in columns col3 and col4.

The desired output would look something like this:

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aaaa aa make ccccc rake cccc | lay | other data | more data |
| bbb bb b make ccccc rake cccc | lay | data | more_data |
| make ccccc | lay | other_data | data |
| rake cccc | lay | other_data | data |
| ddd dddd d make eeeee | may | data more | other data |
| make eeeee | may | more data | data |

I have tried to `groupby()` and `agg()` to list however this messes up the data in the other columns.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html) and [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
# identify make/rake rows
m = df['col1'].str.match('[mr]ake')  # or 'make|rake'

# aggregate the strings
add = df[m].groupby('col2')['col1'].agg(' '.join)

# add the strings in other rows
df['col1'] += df['col2'].map(add).radd(' ').mask(m, '')
```

Output:

```
                            col1 col2        col3        col4
0   aaaa aa make ccccc rake cccc  lay  other data   more data
1  bbb bb b make ccccc rake cccc  lay        data   more_data
2                     make ccccc  lay  other_data        data
3                      rake cccc  lay  other_data        data
4          ddd dddd d make eeeee  may   data more  other data
5                     make eeeee  may   more data        data
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
# Split rows that contains 'make' or 'rake'
mask = df['col1'].str.contains('^(?:make|rake)')

# Join them to create the string to append
suffix = df[mask].groupby('col2')['col1'].agg(' '.join)

# Append the string to the rows with the same 'col2'
df.loc[~mask, 'col1'] += ' ' + df.loc[~mask, 'col2'].map(suffix)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
                            col1 col2        col3        col4
0   aaaa aa make ccccc rake cccc  lay  other data   more data
1  bbb bb b make ccccc rake cccc  lay        data   more_data
2                     make ccccc  lay  other_data        data
3                      rake cccc  lay  other_data        data
4          ddd dddd d make eeeee  may   data more  other data
5                     make eeeee  may   more data        data

>>> df[mask]
         col1 col2        col3  col4
2  make ccccc  lay  other_data  data  # match with 0
3   rake cccc  lay  other_data  data  # match with 0
5  make eeeee  may   more data  data  # match with 4

>>> df[~mask]
         col1 col2        col3        col4
0     aaaa aa  lay  other data   more data  # match with 2 and 3
1    bbb bb b  lay        data   more_data  # no match
4  ddd dddd d  may   data more  other data  # match with 5
```

Answer (score 0):

- identify the rows where `col1` starts with `make` or `rake`
- for each unique value in `col2`, concatenate the `col1` values from these identifies rows
- apply this concatenated string to `col1` for all rows that share the same `col2` value

```
make_rake_rows = df[df['col1'].str.startswith(('make', 'rake'))]

# Create a dictionary to map col2 values to concatenated make/rake strings
make_rake_dict = make_rake_rows.groupby('col2')['col1'].apply(' '.join).to_dict()

# Apply the concatenated string to col1
df['col1'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['col1'] + ' ' + make_rake_dict.get(row['col2'], '')
                      if not row['col1'].startswith(('make', 'rake'))
                      else row['col1'], axis=1)
```